# Interpolating a value between two values

Tags: c++, c, math, interpolation, easing

I'm looking for a function that interpolates a value between two values following a soft curve.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
float xLerp(float mMin, float mMax, float mFactor) { ... }
```

`mFactor` should be between 1 and 0.

How can I create a function similar to the one I drew?

Comment: exponent graph from 0 to 1?  could easily shift or scale as needed...

Comment: So you want a slow start, constant increase in acceleration, and a very sudden stop when it reaches '1' ?

Comment: There is an infinite set of functions which will fit that curve.

Comment: This belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Assuming you know the values at the end points and that the function is strictly increasing and that you don't care too much about precision, a straight line approximation would do. There are a ton of assumptions here and it's not clear what a "soft" curve is. Why exactly don't you know the definition of the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in comment, exponent fits quite well:

```
double mBase = 5; // higher = more "curvy"
double minY = pow(mBase, mMin - mBase);
double maxY = pow(mBase, mMax - mBase);
double scale = (mMax - mMin) / (maxY - minY);
double shift = mMin - minY;
return pow(mBase, mFactor - mBase) * scale + shift;
```

Ugh, slope is all wrong, ugly hack...

Comment: This solution does not provide a slope of `0` at `mFactor == 0`.  This _seems_ to be implied in the graphic.  A solution more in the form of `pow(mFactor, mBase)` where `mBase >= 2` would do it.

Comment: @chux Oh man, you're right.  I'd have to subtract at least 2 from mFactor to even fake it.  Why didn't I hold those things up to each other >.<

Answer (score 2):

A parabola would work.

```
#define ASSERT (cond) // Some assertion macro
/**
 * f(x) = a(x)^2 + 0x + c // b is zero, because no x shift.
 * f(0) = mMin == c = mMin
 * f(1) = mMax == a + mMin = mMax == a = mMax - mMin
 */
float xLerp (float mMin, float mMax, float mFactor) {
    ASSERT(0 <= mFactor && mFactor <= 1);
    float a = mMax - mMin;
    return a * mFactor * mFactor + mMin;
}
```

Comment: Aha! the *other* exponent also works.  `c^n` or `n^c` are both pretty similar I guess.

Answer (score 2):

A sine wave would work.

```
#include <math.h>
#define ASSERT (cond) // some assertion macro
/**
 * f(x) = a * sin(x / t * PI) + b
 * f(0) = mMin == b = mMin
 * f(1) = mMax == a * sin(1/t * pi) + mMin == a * sin(pi/t) = mMax - mMin
 *        a = (mMax - mMin) / sin(pi/t)
 * (Let t == 1 for "normal" periodicity. 0 < t <= 1)
 * a = (mMax - mMin) / sin(pi/t) == a = mMax - mMin
 */
float xLerp (float mMin, float mMax, float mFactor){
    ASSERT(0 <= mFactor && mFactor <= 1);
    float a = mMax - mMin;
    return a * sin(mFactor * PI) + mMin;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about sine waves, but they seemed too "round" somehow...  Very nice simplified solution though.

Comment: Yeah, given your problem statement, it'll come down to your subjective opinion of the right "roundness" :) I hope the general algebra makes sense of how to choose a base function, and scale it to your constraints.

Comment: Not my question.  I was just the one asserting it **looks** like some form of exponent to me.  (the accelerating curve, e^n being the "fastest growing" function, etc)  In any case all 3 answers are fun exercises, and all very tweak able (ie: PI could be smaller value etc)

Comment: @ebyrob whoops, I must have seen your name in the exponent answer and thought that was the Q itself! "Given the problem statement... subjective...".  I do think it might be interesting, though possibly not useful, to use a curve where lim x->1 d/dx === Inf, eg the 4th quadrant of a circle.

Comment: But But!  Circles don't have an "elbow".  Maybe a section of a critically damped system graph... *those* definitely have an elbow.

Comment: @ebyrob we should go shopping for air conditioners - http://xkcd.com/309/